# How to implement Scrollview with LinearLayout using Weight attribute

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

When ever i open keyboard to fill data in this editbox. whole layout is shrinks. I even tried 
    `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

in manifest.xml but still this layout shrinks whenever the keyboard is visible
[When Keyboard is not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi2Eu.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10">

<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:padding="10dp"
android:hint="UserName"
/>

<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:padding="10dp"
android:hint="Address"
/>

<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:padding="10dp"
android:hint="Phone"
/>

<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:padding="10dp"
android:hint="Email"
/>
<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:padding="10dp"
android:hint="Gender"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Please help me how to resolve this issue. Is there is any way to make this layout scrollable.

Comment: Please show your screen.

Answer (score 0):

`layout_weight` used with a `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView` creates view scaling problems. If you want each of your scale equally in the screen, you don't need the `ScrollView`. Check the updated layout below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:hint="UserName"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:hint="Address"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:hint="Phone"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:hint="Gender"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Remove `android:layout_padding="10dp"` property from all your `EditTexts` because there is no *Attribute* available like that.
>
> XML code should be like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:hint="UserName"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:hint="Address"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:hint="Phone"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:hint="Gender"
            android:padding="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`And add Programmatically AdjustPan to your Activity's onCreate method`

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```